# Query Code for Search Engine

Tags: python, sqlite

```
>>> e=searchengine.searcher('searchindex.db')

>>> e.getmatchrows('functional programming') select w0.urlid,w0.location,w1.location from wordlocation w0,wordlocation w1 where w0.urlid=w1.urlid and w0.wordid=10 and w1.wordid=17
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

# it highlights the word select in the program
```

How do I correct this syntax error of the `select` statement? I am using Python with sqlite3.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just plonk SQL into a python file.   This error message is python telling you "I have no idea what select is".

To be more helpful, you'd need to share what library you got "searchengine" from, but no matter what that is, your code is not valid python, so there's no way it's going to work.

Comment: And quite possibly just `e.getmatchrows('functional programming')` may be all you actually need.